# Pass variable from one sub to another

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, adsutil.vbs

How can I pass uniqueId and uniqueId  from sub run to Sub DisplayCustomError. I tried to pass through DisplayCustomError but it's giving "Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub".

Expected result: uniqueId and uniqueId should go to Sub DisplayCustomError to create a json object.

```
sub run
    On Error Resume Next
    wrapper.getVariable( "IRR" ).value = excel.range( "'Cases'!$H$783" )
    Dim uniqueId , uniqueId , errorMessage
    If Err.Number <> 0 And excel.range( "'Cases'!$H$783" ) = "" Then
     errorCode = "MC2006"
     uniqueId = "12"                 
     errorMessage= "Error while executing EVMLite.           
     DisplayCustomError(errorMessage)
     On Error Goto 0         
     Call Err.Raise(vbObjectError + 10, "EVM Failed to execute. ", errorMessage)  
    End If      
end sub

Sub DisplayCustomError(errorMessage)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Dim objHTTP, URL, json, uniqueId, networkInfo, jobId
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")    
    URL = "http://10.93.24.223:9005/vpp/logerror"
    objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
    objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    json = "{""jobId"": """& jobId &""", ""uniqueId"": """& uniqueId &""", ""errorCode"": """& errorCode &""", ""errorMessage"": """& errorMessage &"""}"
    objHTTP.send (json)
 End If
```

end sub

Comment: Use `DisplayCustomError errorMessage` without parentheses or use `Call DisplayCustomError(errorMessage)`. If you want to have multiple arguments, seperate them with commas in your sub definition: `Sub DisplayCustomError(errorMessage as String, UniqueID as Integer, Parameter as Integer)`

Comment: Different topic but: Upon entry to Sub DisplayCustomError(errorMessage) Err.Number will always be zero because the call to .DisplayCustomError() succeeded. So your test for Err.Number will always be false. You already know you have an error so remove the test for Err.Number <> 0.

Comment: @RikSportel I tried to pass as Sub DisplayCustomError(errorMessage as String, UniqueID as Integer, Parameter as Integer)  but it's giving error "Expected ')'"

Comment: Are you sure your code is pasted exactly as it appears in your actual project? The above code shouldnt compile. You have a duplicate declaration as well as a string that wasnt properly closed.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `Call` line from:

```
DisplayCustomError(errorMessage)
```

To:

```
DisplayCustomError errorMessage
```

---

Edit 1: to pass multiple parameters:

First, you need to re-define your `Sub`:

```
Sub DisplayCustomError(errorMessage As String, uniqueId As Long)
```

Then, when you call it, make sure you pass the correct number and type of parameters:

```
DisplayCustomError errorMessage, uniqueId
```

**B.T.W** you can pass the parametes with differnet names and it will still work. For example:

```
DisplayCustomError errorMessage, uniqueId
```

And then

```
Sub DisplayCustomError(errMsg As String, uId As Long)
```

---

**Edit 2**: ***Full code*** edited (relevant parts)

```
Sub run()

    On Error Resume Next
    wrapper.getVariable("IRR").Value = Excel.Range("'Cases'!$H$783")

    ' modified the line below
    Dim uniqueId As String, errorMessage As String

    If Err.Number <> 0 And Excel.Range("'Cases'!$H$783") = "" Then
        ErrorCode = "MC2006"
        uniqueId = "12"
        errorMessage = "Error while executing EVMLite.           "
        DisplayCustomError errorMessage, uniqueId ' <-- modifed this line
        On Error GoTo 0
        Call Err.Raise(vbObjectError + 10, "EVM Failed to execute. ", errorMessage)
    End If

End Sub

Sub DisplayCustomError(errMsg As String, uID As String) ' <-- modifed this line

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Dim objHTTP, URL, json, networkInfo, jobId ' <-- removed uniqueId from this line
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = "http://10.93.24.223:9005/vpp/logerror"
    objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
    objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"

    ' --- modifed the line below ---
    ' *** WHere do you get the value of jobId and ErrorCode ***
    json = "{""jobId"": """ & jobId & """, ""uniqueId"": """ & uID & """, ""errorCode"": """ & ErrorCode & """, ""errorMessage"": """ & errMsg & """}"
    objHTTP.send (json)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I did that but still I am not able to get multiple arguments

Comment: I tried in sub run DisplayCustomError errorMessage, uniqueId 
 and DisplayCustomError(errorMessage As String, uniqueId As String) but Still I am getting error that  Expected ')'

Comment: @DevendraVastrakar try defing the varibales like this `Dim uniqueId As Long , errorMessage As String` (instead of your definition line)

Comment: I defined Dim uniqueId As Long , errorMessage As String  now it's giving error " Expected end of statement"

Comment: @DevendraVastrakar not sure alreay what parameters you want to pass, can you elaborate ? their type, etc.

Comment: Type of I uniqueId and errorMessage are String. I want to pass uniqueId and errorMessage from sub run to sub  DisplayCustomError and errorMessage is successfully going into Sub DisplayCustomError because I have passed errorMessage in DisplayCustomError(errorMessage) but not able to pass uniqueId

Comment: @DevendraVastrakar is `uniqueId` a `Long` or `String` ? because you are setting it to `uniqueId = "12"` which is a `String`, but maybe you want it `As Long`, and then it needs to be `uniqueId = 12`

Comment: yes in uniqueId = "12" is just a hardcoded value. In actual code it's machine name

Comment: @DevendraVastrakar i understand that, but is it a `String` or ` Long` (number) ?

Comment: It's String. Some text is there

Comment: I am getting error for line Dim uniqueId As String, errorMessage As String that Expected end of statement

Comment: @DevendraVastrakar I have no idea why , try resterting excel or something - this error shouldn't happen

Comment: Again it's not working and getting error for line Sub DisplayCustomError(errMsg As String, uID As String) that Expected ')'

Comment: @DevendraVastrakar sorry, I can't help any further, it's running fine on my PC (not getting any of these errors)

Comment: Is time line is working in your machine. can you try to put hardcoded value for  uniqueId and  errorMessage                                            
      Dim uniqueId As String, errorMessage As String